# Django project file - Cannot spot the mistake: "Invalid block tag: 'static'

Tags: django, templates, static, rendering

I have the following error

```
Invalid block tag on line 4: 'static'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

It is being generated by this code (see below) but I cannot (even after having looked through the various similar questions and answers) spot the error.

```
<html>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'wgb/styles.css' %}"/>

</head>

<body>
<div class="login">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required" />
        <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Let me in.</button>
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The error is obviously in this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'wgb/styles.css' %}"/>
```

but I have checked for spaces, order, and spelling/syntax but none of those seem to be the problem.

More specifically, the error notes:
**Error during template rendering** and it is pointing to: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'worldguestbook/styles.css' %}"/>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the static template tag before you can use it. You usually do it in the top of your template file:

```html
{% load static %}

<html>
<head>
....
```

**Source**: [Django docs: Managing static files (e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files)